# Use jQuery to append <li> items from one <ul> to new <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when appending one set of li items from one `ul` to new `ul`.
When I move one it is fine, but when I move two my code duplicates them.

So when I move A & B I get A A B B in the new `ul` instead of A B and I cannot see why.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function moveItems(origin, destination){
  var highlighted = document.querySelectorAll("#leftlist .highlight");
  highlighted.forEach(function(){
    $(origin).clone(true).appendTo(destination);
    $("#leftlist .highlight").remove();

  }
  $("#moveright").click(function(){
    moveItems(".highlight", "#rightlist");
  });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <ul id="leftlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">a item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">b item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">c item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">d item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">e item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">f item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">g item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">h item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">i item</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">j item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<ul id="rightlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
</ul>
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] You are missing a lot of brackets in the code you have pasted

Comment: Also. try to collect all elements in the loop, and append only once. DOM changes are expensive.

Comment: There's no need to clone the elements.  Appending an already attached element to a new location will automatically detach it from its existing parent.

Comment: please review my answer demonstrating how this should just be a one-liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code logic is far too complicated - there's no need to `.clone()` and `.remove()` at all.

Appending an already attached element to a new location will automatically detach it from its existing parent.

Also, jQuery's `.appendTo` method will quite happily move several elements at once, avoiding the need for a `.forEach` call:

```
$('#moveright').on('click', function() {
  $('#leftlist .highlight').appendTo('#rightlist').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```js
$('#moveright').on('click', function() {
  $('#leftlist .highlight').appendTo('#rightlist').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="moveright">
Move To Right
</button>
<div><span></span>
  <ul id="leftlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">a item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">b item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item highlight">c item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">d item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">e item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item highlight">f item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">g item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">h item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">i item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">j item</li>
  </ul>
  </span><span>
<ul id="rightlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
</ul></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```js
function transferListItems($source,$destination){
  var $highlighted = $source.find('.highlight');
  $highlighted.clone(true).appendTo($destination);
}

$('#transfer').click(function(){
  transferListItems($('#list1'),$('#list2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>List 1</h5>
<ul id="list1">
  <li class="highlight">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li class="highlight">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li class="highlight">Five</li>
</ul>
<button id="transfer">Transfer</button>
<h5>List 2</h5>
<ul id="list2">
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, look at the part inside forEach statement. Inside the loop you're selecting all the "origin" and cloning those. This is why you see duplicate copies.

I modified this part and add some functionalities that would be similar to what you are going to implement.

leftlist is bordered by red line and rightlist is bordered by blue line.

Click one or more items in the leftlist(items in the red box) and press the button. You can see that those selected items are moved to rightlist(to the blue box).

```js
function hightlightOnClick (e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass("highlight");
}

function moveItems (origin, destination) {  
  $(origin).clone(true).appendTo(destination);
  $("#leftlist .highlight").remove();
  
  // we don't want items in the rightbox to respond to click event any more.
  $(".highlight").off("click", hightlightOnClick);  

  // detaches highlight classes from every item.
  $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
}

$("#leftlist .list-group-item").click(hightlightOnClick);

$("#moveright").click(function () {  
 moveItems("#leftlist .highlight", "#rightlist");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}

#leftlist {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#rightlist {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="moveright">
Move To Right
</button>
<ul id="leftlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">a item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">b item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">c item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">d item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">e item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">f item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">g item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">h item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">i item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">j item</li>
</ul>

<ul id="rightlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
</ul>
```